# In Job 40:14, what does Job have to accomplish in order for the LORD to admit that Job can save himself?

Tags: soteriology, job

> Brenton LXX Job 40:14 [Then] will I confess that thy right hand can save [thee].

> KJV Job 40:14 Then will I also confess unto thee that thine own right hand can save thee.

Apparently, the LORD is willing to admit that Job can save himself if he meets the requirements. What are those requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those requirements are that Job also have God's power (and thus be God). In other words, it is impossible for Job's own power to save himself.

In the immediate passage it is a reference to (LEB citations):

- *Or do you have an arm like God,* Does Job have the same power that God has?
- *And can you thunder with a voice like His?*  Can Job speak through thunder and other mighty forces of nature as God can?
- *“Adorn yourself with eminence and dignity, And clothe yourself with honor and majesty.*  Can Job match God's majesty, eminence, and dignity?
- *“Pour out the overflowings of your anger, And look on everyone who is proud, and make him low. “Look on everyone who is proud, and humble him, And tread down the wicked where they stand. “Hide them in the dust together; Bind them in the hidden place.* Is Job able to humble all who are proud, overcome them, destroy them where they stand, and throw them into Sheol/Hell/The grave?

If Job can do all of these things, then he can rely on his own strength to save himself.

Comment: Great stuff, Robert. Can you please identify the verses that you are citing? That would make your answer so much more compelling. Thanks!

Comment: These are the verses immediately preceeding the verse you cited in Job 40